# Sonarqube gradle plugin coverage with Lombok

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, lombok

I have a class annotated with Lombok's @Data, in a gradle project, using the Sonarqube and Jacoco plugins.

The source code is available [here on github](https://github.com/andrewmaye/sonarqube-lombok)

I have a locally running [sonarqube server](https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube/) running as a docker container, started like this:

```
docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 sonarqube
```

I have added a "lombok.config" file, asking it to add @Lombok.Generated annotations to its generated code, as per the Global Config keys section [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration) in the docs.

```
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

And I have the following Sonar condition configuration.

[image]

When I run the sonarqube target for the very first time, it reports that the project passes.

[image]

If I then switch the lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation to be false, and rerun the sonarqube target, it reports that there is a failure:

[image]

If I then switch the lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation back to true, and rerun again, sonarqube reports that the project is still failed. And I can't get the project to pass again.

I then changed the group name in the build.gradle file, to force the sonarqube gradle plugin to create a new project within the Sonarqube server. When I do this, the project passes again.

I've never changed any of the source code during this process.

Please does anyone have an idea why Sonarqube is behaving this way?

Answer (score 3):

> I've never changed any of the source code during this process.

Oh, but you have. Or rather, Lombok has by inserting (or not) annotations in your code.

You're using a Quality Gate that looks only at "New Code". On your first analysis, no code is new, so none of it is up for consideration. Then you twiddle your Lombok settings, regenerate and reanalyze. Lombok apparently makes *some* changes in your code. I've never used Lombok so I can't expand on exactly what's happening here, but you can click through on the New Coverage-related metrics on the project homepage to get to a list of files. Drill into a file to see what's being considered "new" in it (yellow highlight). Look to the marginal markings (red, green, yellow striped) to see what's considered covered.

**N.B.** Your quality gate currently demands 99% coverage on conditions in new code. This is unrealistic and past the point of diminishing returns. You should reconsider this value. IMO 85-95% is more realistic depending on your team.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't the condition coverage is on all code, rather than new code? If you edit the quality gate, I can see options to add a "condition coverage", or a "condition coverage on new code".  We inehrited those settings from another team. I can see your point regarding 99%.  Anyway - I noticed that the SonarJava plugin was v4.x. The v5.1.1 plugin had a fix to use Jacoco 0.8.0 - when we updated the plugin, our Lombok generated code no longer seems to be checked.  I'm just starting out with both Sonarqube and lombok, so all a learning experience...

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, we found that the problem was solved by updating the SonarJava plugin to the newest 5.1.1 release.

I think this ticket in release 5.1, to upgrade to Jacoco 0.8.0 may be the thing that started to honour the @Lombok.Generated annotation.

[image]